# Service not started exception when running C# program at startup

Tags: c#, startup

I have a system tray application which gets installed and starts running from a logon script.

The program is failing on startup because it says that a service is not started but I don't know which one it is.

I thought it was the RPC service (name=RpcSs).  Here is what I tried but didn't work:

```
string ServiceName_Rpc = "RpcSs";
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(ServiceName_Rpc);
controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
```

---

> The Server service is not started. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070842)
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoMachineInit()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet.get_CurrentAsPrincipal()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.get_Current()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says which service in the error message:

> The **Server** service is not started

The Server service:

> Supports file, print, and named-pipe
>   sharing over the network for this
>   computer. If this service is stopped,
>   these functions will be unavailable.
>   If this service is disabled, any
>   services that explicitly depend on it
>   will fail to start.

Try changing your code to wait for this service and see if you have any luck. Although, I'm not sure what you're doing which requires this service, so can't guarantee it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I didn't realize that "Server" was a service. I totally misinterpreted the message.